# Why in JS a.test = 1 when "a" is a number doesn't throw an error

Tags: javascript

I tested this today and I don't understand the behaviour. For me, that should be an error.

```js
const a = 1;
a.test = 1;

console.log(a)
console.log(a.test)
```

Someone have the answer ?

Comment: Short answer: because (almost) everything is an object - see the dupe for more information. Long answer: Because the JS data typing model was built on a Friday afternoon and everyone was already drunk.

Comment: When you use a primitive like an object (like calling the `toString` method), it's actually converted to the object counterpart (i.e a number to the `Number` object). Your changes are then on the object counterpart. After that, the object counterpart is discarded.

Comment: Probably something around the fact that everything is an object. EDIT: caTS did a much better job of what i was trying to say.

Comment: @ste2425 not everything is an object. That's absolutely the wrong mental model to use. It's not useful as a shorthand, since it then supposes that rules that are applicable for object would apply to primitives or vice versa.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  `and everyone was already drunk. `,, oh in that case I think I'd better get some bears, as the JS object model goes down in my books as one of the best data structures in any language.. :)

Comment: @VLAZ correction then, because most everything *Leads* back to an object.

Comment: @ste2425 which is still incorrect - `null` and `undefined` aren't and don't have object representation. And I don't see how it's useful to think of symbols as having connection to objects. Seems weird.

Comment: @VLAZ that's why i said most. It is a generalization. However i will bow out to your better judgement. I can see I'm fighting your "got-to-be-right-itus".

Answer (score 0):

you can define properties pretty much anything, but in this case you are assigning it to a `number` which doesn't actually hold properties.